# How to link to another page using webview

Tags: html, android-studio, webview

I have it so from index.html you hit a link that brings you to page.html but when I go to page.html it says. Ive tried making it assets/page.html says the same thing, tried file:///android_asset/page.html that didnt work

```html
<html xmlns:width="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>


<body>

<div class="head">
    <h1>head</h1>
</div>

<a href="page.html"><table>
    <tr>
        <th style="width:85px;"><img src="icon.png" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%"></th>
        <th class="appname"> Site <p class="apppub" style="text-align:left;">creator</p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>desc</td>
    </tr>

</table></a>







</body>




</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

changing it to anything but "page.html" worked